# How to add TailwindCSS to Vue3 apps relying on the Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css

Based on the guides on [how to setup TailwindCSS for specific frameworks](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/framework-guides) I'm trying to add it to my new Vue 3 app. I'm not using Vite yet but couldn't find a Vue CLI guide.

I know there is the [vue-cli-plugin-tailwind](https://github.com/forsartis/vue-cli-plugin-tailwind/tree/master) solving this but the current version is in beta so I would like to do it on my own for now.

First I created a Vue 3 app using the Vue CLI. After that I followed the [guide for Angular apps](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular)

- `npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer`
- `npx tailwindcss init`
- Inside the *tailwind.config.js*  file use this content

.

```
  content: [
    "./public/index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
```

- Create a new file *./src/styles.css*

.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

- Inside the *main.ts* file add `import "./styles.css";`
- Add the following code to the *App.vue* file

.

```
  <div class="bg-red-500">
    Background should be red
  </div>
```

Unfortunately the background is not red.

Does someone know how to setup the project?

Comment: The second part of the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71760994/how-to-debug-a-vuejs-3-typescript-project-with-vs-code-and-chrome-using-sourcema) should solve your problem.